# Convert web.config file(s) to launchsettings in .Net Core 3.1

Tags: .net-core, web-config, visual-studio-2019

I am running Visual Studio 2019, C#, .Net Core 3.1

I have inherited a web app.  The project has a `web.config` file.  The docs say that `web.config` files are not needed any more but I am not sure how to move the info in the existing `web.config` file into whatever should replace it.

The pruned file looks like the following.  The `...` below replace more than 15 similar lines

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<configuration>
    <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
        <system.webServer>
            <rewrite>
                <rewriteMaps>
                    <rewriteMap name="(.*)" />
                </rewriteMaps>
                <rules>
                    <rule name="Redirect to HTTPS" stopProcessing="true">
                        <match url="(.*)" />
                        <conditions>
                            <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
                        </conditions>
                        <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" appendQueryString="true" />
                    </rule>
                </rules>
            </rewrite>
            <handlers>
                <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
                
                <add name="handler-wa-32" path="*" verb="*" modules="IsapiModule"
                     scriptProcessor="C:\Program Files\thing\webagent\win32\bin\ISAPI6WebAgent.dll" resourceType="Unspecified"
                     requireAccess="None" preCondition="classicMode,bitness32" />
                     
                <add name="thirdPartyWebAgentHandler-abc-32" path="*.abc" verb="*" modules="thirdPartyWebAgentModule-32"
                     resourceType="Unspecified" preCondition="integratedMode,bitness32" />
                ...
                
                <add name="handler-wa" path="*" verb="*" modules="IsapiModule"
                     scriptProcessor="C:\Program Files\thing\webagent\win64\bin\ISAPI6WebAgent.dll" resourceType="Unspecified"
                     requireAccess="None" preCondition="classicMode,bitness64" />
                <add name="thirdPartyWebAgentHandler-abc" path="*.abc" verb="*" modules="thirdPartyWebAgentModule"
                     resourceType="Unspecified" preCondition="integratedMode,bitness64" />
                ...
                
            </handlers>
            <aspNetCore processPath="%LAUNCHER_PATH%" arguments="%LAUNCHER_ARGS%" stdoutLogEnabled="true"
                        stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="InProcess">
                
                <handlerSettings>
                    <handlerSetting name="debugFile" value="aspnetcore-debug.log" />
                    <handlerSetting name="debugLevel" value="FILE,TRACE" />
                </handlerSettings>
            </aspNetCore>
            <modules>
                <add name="thirdPartyWebAgentModule" preCondition="integratedMode,bitness64" />
                <add name="thirdPartyWebAgentModule-32" preCondition="integratedMode,bitness32" />
            </modules>
            <isapiFilters>
                <filter name="ThirdParty Agent" path="C:\Program Files\thing\webagent\win64\bin\ISAPI6WebAgent.dll" enabled="true"
                        preCondition="classicMode,bitness64" />
                <filter name="ThirdParty Agent-32" path="C:\Program Files\thing\webagent\win32\bin\ISAPI6WebAgent.dll" enabled="true"
                        preCondition="classicMode,bitness32" />
            </isapiFilters>
        </system.webServer>
    </location>
</configuration>
```

I assume these things go into the `launchsettings.json` file but I am not sure how to name or position the items.

Advice or examples welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what documentation you read, but that's incorrect. The `web.config` file is used by IIS, and should be included in the project.

Refer to [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/web-config?view=aspnetcore-6.0)

> In order to set up the ASP.NET Core Module correctly, the web.config file must be present at the content root path (typically the app base path) of the deployed app.

Comment: Hi, my probably incorrect understanding comes from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/configuration?view=aspnetcore-3.1  

Specifically the "Migrate configuration settings from web.config" section.

Comment: OK I understand. Going form .Net Framework does require a lot of config settings to be moved as in the example link. `ConnectionString` is one of them. You move some, but not all elements in `web.config` to `appsettings.json`. Here is more information: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-6.0 See the `Other configuration` for more information on the `launch.json`, `launchsettings.json` and `web.config` files